# Where is the "program" module that some bash scripts require before launching Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, bash, require, environment

I found a Bash script today that uses the *env* command to launch Node.JS.  The script requires two packages and then uses the second package to parse the *process* command line arguments before launching node as shown below:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

require('zos-lib').Logger.silent(false);
require('./program').parse(process.argv);
```

I can't find a module/package named **'./program'** *anywhere* in my file system.  Can someone tell me where the *program* module/package is and what it does?  I tried many Google searches but unfortunately *program* is such a common keyword that I'm not finding anything useful.

**UPDATE**: *slebetman's* answer is correct.  I wanted to explain why I couldn't find the *program* module in this update, in case it helps others.  As soon as I read his answer about that script being a Javascript script and to look for **program.js** *not* **program** I found it by searching the directory tree from the top level *Node.js* directory with this command:

```
$ find . -iname program.js
```

Unfortunately for me, what you see below is what I tried the first time and that does not produce any output:

```
$ find . -iname program
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script you found is not a bash script. It is a javascript script. Specifically it is a script written in javascript for node.js.

In node's `require` system, a module name that begins with `./` means that the module is in the same folder as the script.

You haven't told us the file name of the script you posted. But lets assume it's called `myscript.js`. Then the folder structure should be:

```
/whatever/folder/myscript.js
/whatever/folder/program.js
```

or

```
/whatever/folder/myscript.js
/whatever/folder/program/index.js
```

or

```
/whatever/folder/myscript.js
/whatever/folder/program/package.json
/whatever/folder/program/whatever_script_name.js
```

If you cannot find the file `program.js` or the folder `program` in the same folder as the script you are looking at then you haven't copied the script properly (you forgot to copy the "program" file or folder).

Comment: Thanks!  That did it.  Please see my update to my answer that explains why I couldn't find anything until I read your reply.  One confusion still.  What's a shebang line doing in a Javascript file?  That plus the fact the loading script is definitely named "zos" and *not* "zos.js" really helped muddy the waters.